I'm getting this error when trying to upload an image
When I select the image, I get this error:
file_put_contents(C:\Users\Diih\Desktop\workspace2\stbox\storage/tenantdiogo3\framework/cache/facade-1e06026dbe325cba543b2306bd7e55d66d31e4c1.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory
I am working with Laravel 11 and Livewire 3. From what I researched, it seems to be a cache directory issue, but I didn't understand how to resolve it.
I tried uploading an image, and it caused this error:
file_put_contents(C:\Users\Diih\Desktop\workspace2\stbox\storage/tenantdiogo3\framework/cache/facade-1e06026dbe325cba543b2306bd7e55d66d31e4c1.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory
The expected outcome is to upload the image successfully.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

share your code so other can guide you in best way, no body can tell any solution without seeing what is happening in the code.

The error tells you that the folder you are trying to send the image file to is not available.
Check the folder name and make sure you are targeting the correct file path.
